# How to get a file in one container that is in another container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that describes several containers.

I need to use a file in container C that is in container A.

Tell me, please, how can this be done? I don't understand the examples from the documentation.

Comment: Share a `docker volume` between A and C maybe? Or mount a directory on your host to both A and C?

Comment: Docker containers are designed so that their filesystems are isolated from each other and from the host.  Can you redesign the system so that one container makes something like an HTTP GET request to get the file, rather than depending on a shared filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

If files are under `volume`, you can access file with your server (root account probably).

Else, you should first:

```
docker cp container_a:/path/to/file /path/in/your/server
docker cp /path/in/your/server container_c:/path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to do it exclusively through docker compose?

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

**1) using Docker volume**
Here share same asset-volume between two containers

```
version: '3'
services:
  A:
    volumes:
      - asset-volume:/path/a/assets
  B:
    volumes:
      - asset-volume:/path/b/assets

volumes:
  asset-volume:
```

2. Using a host directory
   Here share same host assets directory between two containers

> ```
> version: '3'
> services:
>   A:
>     volumes:
>       - ./assets:/path/a/assets
>   B:
>     volumes:
>       - ./assets:/path/b/assets
> ```

Comment: In both of these cases, the contents of the named volume or host directory will hide whatever's in the image.  That is, these don't let you share content from one image to another; they replace the content in both images with something else, that happens to be shared.